# Database design relationship cycle

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, relationship, cycle

I was wondering if there is another way to create this database without cycle.
The scenario is:
-Every student has to choose one teacher
-Every student can choose one lesson but it is not required property.
-Every teacher has many lessons.

so I tried to design my database like the image below :

[image]

but I am getting this error when I try to set ON DELETE CASCADE:
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Student_Lesson' on table 'Student' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I want to Delete All lessons and students related to teacher when user delete the teacher.
Have I to change my design or I have to set ON DELETE NO ACTION and control the delete process by code ?

Comment: I think you have a flaw in the DB design. The student can have one or more lessons, which can have a teacher. There is no need for student to have a teacher directly

Comment: Yes I know but as I told the scenario is different here and the customer want student to choose teacher as required property, and to choose just zero or one lesson.

Comment: Then you have to remove one of the cascades.

Comment: Note that your current design will allow a student to select  a lesson for a different teacher than the one assigned to the student.

Comment: @DanGuzman yes I noticed that but I couldnt find better design for this scenario